# Get dictionary values as List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, dataframe

I know this is asked earlier, but I tried but could not help.

I have below dictionary, want to convert to List, What is the best way to convert to List

```
dct = {'result': ['activeaddresses', 'exchangevolume(usd)', 'marketcap(usd)', 'mediantxvalue(usd)', 'price(usd)', 'txcount', 'txvolume(usd)']}

dList = list(dct.values())
```

Result:

```
[['activeaddresses', 'exchangevolume(usd)', 'marketcap(usd)', 'mediantxvalue(usd)', 'price(usd)', 'txcount', 'txvolume(usd)']]
```

I need splitted List:

```
['activeaddresses', 'exchangevolume(usd)', 'marketcap(usd)', 'mediantxvalue(usd)', 'price(usd)', 'txcount', 'txvolume(usd)']
```

Later, I want to compare list of items in "dList" with another List.

Comment: Append this line in your code `dlist = [i for i in dlist[0]]`

Comment: Why not just `dList = dct['result']`?

Comment: @trozen, working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary have only one value and that itself is a list of elements. So just call the `result` key and you will get the list value.

If you want the list from your code add the index `[0]` like,

`dList = list(dct.values())[0]`

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: No. If you want the value associated to 'result', just call `dct['result']`. Don't hope that the dict really only has 1 element or that it will be correctly sorted and used in Python 3.6 or newer.

Comment: @EricDuminil I have mentioned the same in line1.

Answer (score 4):

If you know that the list is the value associated to the `'result'` key, simply call `dct['result']`.

```
>>> dct = {'result': ['activeaddresses', 'exchangevolume(usd)', 'marketcap(usd)', 'mediantxvalue(usd)', 'price(usd)', 'txcount', 'txvolume(usd)']}
>>> dct
{'result': ['activeaddresses', 'exchangevolume(usd)', 'marketcap(usd)', 'mediantxvalue(usd)', 'price(usd)', 'txcount', 'txvolume(usd)']}
>>> dct['result']
['activeaddresses', 'exchangevolume(usd)', 'marketcap(usd)', 'mediantxvalue(usd)', 'price(usd)', 'txcount', 'txvolume(usd)']
```

Converting the values to a list is unneeded, inefficient and might return the wrong value if your dict has more than 1 (key, value) pair.